# Ruby Dropped in Netbeans 7,How to Use it in Netbeans7?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans-7

In Netbeans 7, Ruby support was dropped:

> Although our Ruby support has
>   historically been well received, based
>   on existing low usage trends we are
>   unable to justify the continued
>   allocation of resources to support the
>   feature.

How can I use it in Netbeans 7?

Comment: Please don't mass-edit your posts, especially if it's only to put them in Title Case, which isn't an improvement.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I followed the steps described in this blog post - http://blog.enebo.com/2011/02/installing-ruby-support-in-netbeans-70.html  and it works. Enjoy

> Click Tools -> Plugins Click on 
>   'Settings' tab Click on 'Add' button
>   to get Update Center Customizer popup
>   Set name to 'Beta 1' Set URL: to
>   'http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/beta/stable/catalog.xml.gz'
>   Press 'OK' Click to 'Available
>   Plugins' Click 'Reload Catalog' Choose
>   'Ruby and Rails' Pat yourself on the
>   back

Edit: now ruby on rails plugin can be found directly at "Tools">"Plugins">"Available Plugins">"Ruby And Rails" (if you don't find this plugin at the provided path you should download and install the latest netbeans ide)

Reedit: if you need Ruby On Rails support for Netbeans 7.1 check http://blog.enebo.com/2012/01/workaround-for-ruby-support-on-netbeans.html

Comment: I've just installed netbeans 7.0.1. As said above, 'Tools->Plugins->Available Plugins->Ruby and Rails' is there out of the box and working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: For 7.2 use this   https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/resource/nb-72-community-ruby.xml

Answer (score 29):

*Oracle* stopped supporting the NetBeans Ruby plugin, but the development has been taken over by the community. In fact, there are now *more* people working on the plugin than back when Oracle *did* still support it, including three of the lead developers of JRuby, one of the original developers of the NetBeans Ruby plugin and one former NetBeans core developer, all of whom would probably not be working on it if it was still controlled by Oracle.

They are still using the NetBeans source control repository, the NetBeans project infrastructure, the NetBeans build server, the NetBeans plugin server, … in order to keep the transition as seamless as possible.

Pretty much the only difference is that you can no longer select the plugin directly in the installer, you have to install NetBeans first and then install it via the plugin menu, just like every other plugin, like the Scala or Clojure plugins, for example.

Just download and install the All-In-One Edition, deactivate all options except `Base IDE` during installation and install the Ruby plugin afterwards.

The plugin center for Ruby from the Continuous Integration server is http://Deadlock.NetBeans.Org/hudson/job/ruby/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml

Comment: Fails on install with: The plugin HTML Editor is requested in version >= 1.6 (release version 1) but only 2.4.1 (of release version different from 1) was found. Needs an update.

Comment: @joshmckin: I haven't used NetBeans in a while. Does this help: http://Blog.Enebo.Com/2012/01/workaround-for-ruby-support-on-netbeans.html ?

Comment: sorry but no. I could try and modify the source to rebuild the plugin with updated requirements but I cannot find a public repo.

Comment: Forgot to mention this is NetBeans 7.2

Comment: this is the best one for current versions http://Deadlock.NetBeans.Org/hudson/job/ruby/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml  thanks........ @Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 8):

**NetBeans 7.3**:

You can install the *Ruby and Rails* plugin for NetBeans 7.3.x directly from the plugin portal:

> http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549

Here are some installation instructions:

> https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/ruby_on_rails_in_netbeans

**NetBeans 7.2**:

To install the *Ruby on Rails* plugin for NetBeans 7.2 add this update center in `Tools -> Plugins -> Settings`:

> https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/resource/nb-72-community-ruby.xml

Obtained from Geertjan's Blog:

> https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/ruby_in_netbeans_ide_7

**Building the plugin from sources**: I used and built the sources linked from Geertjan's Blog:

> http://hg.netbeans.org/community-ruby

When building the plugin NetBeans (it took a very long time), I got the following error:

```
Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml. It could not be found
```

This can be fixed by installing `ant-contrib` on your system, e.g.:

> yum -y install ant-contrib

Find the JAR file (in my case it was located at `/usr/share/java/ant/ant-contrib.jar`) and add it to Ant's classpath in NetBeans through `Tools -> Options -> Java -> Ant -> Add JAR/ZIP`.

After that it should build. If you want to use the plugins, right-click the `NB Ruby` project and click on `Package As -> NBMs`. This will create an *Update Center*. You can add this update update center to your NetBeans via `Tools -> Plugins -> Settings -> Add` where the URL should be:

> file:/PathToTheRepository/build/updates/updates.xml

After that you can install the `Ruby and Rails` plugin.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails support is now included in the default modules list.  I have not been able to find a download with just the netbeans ide (no additional plugins) so I download the php bundle and then uninstall all the php plugins and install the Ruby on Rails plugin.

I would suggest also installing the git and scss plugins.  The scss plugin is not yet in the default plugin list for 7.0, but you can get an nbm for it [here](http://code.google.com/p/scss-editor/).  I install the 0.1 version, not the 0.3 beta version.

The full list of plugins I REMOVE are: Bugzilla, CVS, Hudson, Mercurial, PHP, PHP Documentor Tag Help, PHP Symfony Framework, PHP Zend Framework, Software as a Service, Subversion.  Of course if you use any of these, you may not want to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this answer does not provide a technical solution to the question, but it is an answer of sorts. If you would like to see Oracle include official Ruby support in Netbeans again, please consider signing the following petition:

http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/re-include-ruby-support-in-netbeans/

Answer (score 2):

For Netbeans 7.3 you can install the [recently](https://twitter.com/tom_enebo/status/319832359509839872) released [Ruby and Rails plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549) by Tom Enebo.

You can follow these installation steps by nichot20:

1. Download the package (containing .jar, .nbm files and updates.xml)
2. Go to the plugins->settings tab
3. Add a new "Update Center" with a url of the form: `file:///path/to/updates.xml`
4. Do a refresh and then it all appears it the list of plug ins.