# ruby and netbeans customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-7.1

I have installed NetBeans 7.1. But I did not get the Ruby and Rails plugin on that.
So according to [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736417/ruby-dropped-in-netbeans-7-how-to-use-it-in-netbeans7), I did the following:

1. Click `Tools -> Plugins` Click on `'Settings' tab` Click on `'Add'` button to get Update Center Customizer popup.
2. Set name to `'Beta 1'` Set URL to http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/beta/stable/catalog.xml.gz
3. Press 'OK' Click to 'Available Plugins' Click 'Reload Catalog' Choose.

After that I got Ruby and Rails as an Available Plugin. But when I try to install that I got one pop up window having the error message

> Welcome to the NetBeans IDE Plugin Installer The installer will
>   download, verify and then install the selected plugins.
>
> Some plugins require plugin HTML Editor Library to be installed. The
>   plugin HTML Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.21 (release
>   version 1) but only 2.0.1 (of release version different from 1) was
>   found.  The following plugins are affected:       Ruby and Rails
>         Spellchecker Ruby Language Bindings

So what I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: hurrray! I have resolve this..

Comment: Fair enough. Mind telling us **how** you fixed it? If the answer differs from Ariejan's, please create a new one and mark it as the answer. If Ariejan's helped you out instead, mark his answer as the right one. It's common courtesy rewarding people that waste your time for you on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I've now read about three or four questions from you, all about you fighting NetBeans and have got nothing to do with Ruby on Rails.

Stop fighting your editor. Your editor or IDE should make life **easier** for you, not more difficult. If it fails to achieve that goal for you, stop using it.

You. Do. Not. Need. NetBeans.

Use a normal text editor and use a console/terminal to use Rails' built-in commands. This will

- make your life easier
- allow you to start writing code **now**
- make it easier to get help if you get stuck with Rails itself.

Comment: thanks,one good news for me that is slowly slowly I am able to solve issues and hope within a very days it will be solved, just need your help whenever need.

Comment: Has nothing to do with RoR? Indeed, it's the PHP plugin in Netbeans that is causing these issues! Seriously though, there's ample reasons why one would want to use Netbeans to get this job done. For instance, I just needed to edit a RoR project, think my life would be easier if I did that in Netbeans? It's like telling a designer to  switch over to MSPaint from Photoshop...

Comment: You've got a good point, people shouldn't fight there editor...on the other hand, giving up on some stupid reason is..well..stupid. I wouldn't give up editing big projects in Netbeans just because they stopped supporting Ruby, for instance. Either case, it's *always* worth it to ask for help. If that fails, or if you recon you wasted enough time fighting, well, by all means switch to something else. *However, switching earlier won't automagically fix all issues.*